# Writing an "if" statement to compare strings within a stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, string

i am write to write a if statement inside a procedure that compares the first 3 characters of a string like: 
8005456566

and if the first 3 characters are:
800
855
866
877

it won't go into the statement.

Comment: *"it won't go into the statement."* show us what you have

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE mystring LIKE '800%' OR mystring LIKE '855%'...`...You should add the things you've tried.  I didn't down vote, but that's why it happened :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MySQL procedures, the conditional would be written more like this:

```
IF (VariableUsed LIKE '800%' OR VariableUsed LIKE '855%' OR VariableUsed LIKE '866%' OR VariableUsed LIKE '877%) THEN
    # code to execute if the string starts with any of the specified numbers
END IF;
```

Each of those individual statements (VariableUsed LIKE someString) checks to see if the first three characters match the first three characters in the specified string ('800' or '855' etc.) plus any amount of characters afterward ('%' symbol means any amount of characters).  This is the standard syntax for MySQL stored procedure conditionals. Also see: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if.html

EDIT:
If you want to do something different for each of the conditions, you would organize it more like this:

```
IF (VariableUsed LIKE '800%') THEN
    # code to execute;
ELSE IF (VariableUsed LIKE '855%') THEN
    # code to execute;
ELSE IF (VariableUsed LIKE '866%') THEN
    # code to execute;
ELSE IF (VariableUsed LIKE '877%) THEN
    # code to execute;
ELSE
    # code to execute if none of these are true;
END IF;
```

This will gaurentee that something will come about from executing the if statement, even if it does not recognize the beginning string.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.column LIKE '800%' OR table1.column LIKE '855%' OR table1.column LIKE '866%' OR table1.column LIKE '877%'
```

% searches for a partial match in the `string`. [This link](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/like.php) gives some good explanations of the identifiers you can use.